# Проблема в Android Studio с классами

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здравствуйте, как совместить 2 кода в один. Конфликт одного названия класса. Нужно Fragment и Activity. 
public class Set1 extends Fragment

public class Set1 extends Activity

1 часть

```
public class Set1 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View set1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.set1_frag, container, false);

    return set1;
    }}
```

2 часть кода (нужно совместить с 1)

```
public class Set1 extends Activity {
Button btnLogout;
Button changepas;
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    changepas = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btchangepass);
    btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    /**
     * Hashmap to load data from the Sqlite database
     **/
     HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
     user = db.getUserDetails();
    /**
     * Change Password Activity Started
     **/
    changepas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0){

            Intent chgpass = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChangePassword.class);

            startActivity(chgpass);
        }

    });

   /**
    *Logout from the User Panel which clears the data in Sqlite database
    **/
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
            logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
            Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
            login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(login);
            finish();
        }
    });
/**
 * Sets user first name and last name in text view.
 **/
        final TextView login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textwelcome);
        login.setText("Welcome  "+user.get("fname"));
        final TextView lname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        lname.setText(user.get("lname"));
    }}
```

**Обновление**

Постараюсь объяснить подробно и нормально. У меня было две части кода, я их совместил. это была регистрация и меню (верхнее меню), далее я создал 4 подменю (главная, основная, запасная, настройки). Проблема возникла с подменю - настройки. Скопировал .xml код настроек регистрации. Решил совместить код, который относится к меню с настройками регистрации. Но стакнулся с проблемой если переименовать Fragment в Activity то вылезает куча ошибок. Совместить у меня не получатся. По этому обратился за помощью выложив фрагменты из приложения.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните, в чем состоит проблема, или укажите дополнительную информацию, чтобы стало ясно, в чем именно заключается вопрос. Сейчас практически невозможно понять, о чем именно вы спрашиваете. Чтобы разобраться, как правильно оформлять вопросы, посетите страницу "как задавать вопросы".

Comment: Нужно объединить эти 2 кода в один. Проблема заключается в том, что при соединении 2х проектов возникла ошибка о дублировании класса.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, в одном из проектов рефакторингом измените название класса на такое, которое не повторяется в другом проекте, хотя ваш вопрос более, чем абсолютно полностью не понятен.

Comment: Есть меню (фрагмент кода - часть 1), в него хочу вставить часть вторую, что бы кнопки были кликтабельны.

Comment: вы хотите в фрагмент вставить активити что ли ? Чем больше вы пытаетесь что то объяснить, тем более непонятно становится. Если вам нужна логика клики отрабатывать, зачем что то куда то вставлять - просто пишите код и все. делов на минуту. Не могу постигнуть, как у вас получается совпадение имен классов, если вам нужна логика для кликов? Вы в фрагмент целиком код активити вставляете или что куда .. напишите, то что у вас получилось в итоге что ли наверное.

Comment: обращаясь по нику, пишите его с "собаки" , например @Дмитрий - тогда сообщение придет к адресату в ящик и он его не пропустит. Вам нужно вторую часть кода преобразовать из активити в фрагмент?

Comment: @pavlofff , Если нет возможности запустить фрагмент и активити одновременно. Если преобразовать это во фрагмент то код будет нормально работать? Спасибо большое.

Comment: Конечно можно запустить активити , а в ней фрагмент - вопрос только в размещении виджетов того и другого на экране. Можно и преобразовать активти в фрагмент .. Все можно, для этого только нужно, чтобы вы определились с конкретной задачей, которую вы не можете решить самостоятельно и переписали ваш вопрос так, чтобы и другим было понятно, что вы хотите и не можете самостоятельно сделать. Это нужно для того, чтобы на ваш вопрос можно было дать законченный однозначный ответ - пока все это какая то абстракция с едва уловимым смыслом, на которую ответить нечего.

Comment: Конкретно по вашему сейчас поставленному вопросу - просто переименуйте имя фрагмента и все обращения к нему из `set1` в любое другое имя, хоть бы в `set2`

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно чтобы 2 класса с одинаковым именем сосуществовали в одном приложении, разложите их по пакетам (packages).

К примеру, пакет приложения `com.mydomain.mobile.myapp`, здесь будет *Activity*, a *Fragment* переместить в `com.mydomain.mobile.myapp.fragments`.

Этот вопрос к Android Studio, да и к Android не имеет отношения.